# Can you print n’th fibonaci sequence using python? (it includes some conditions though)

Tags: python

Can you guys print the n’th fibonaci sequence when n is given? (Using python)
BUT you can’t use `import, for, while, if, elif, else, is, True, False, <, >, =, +, -, *, /, %, &, |, ^, ~, [, ], {, }, ‘, “, and numbers (0~9)`

Can anyone solve this quiz???

Comment: You mean you *can't*? In any case, you really need to look at [ask] and the [help]

Comment: That is a lot of forbidden symbols

Comment: SO is here to help you solve problems with code you've written, not to write the code for you - as a result, it's also not a good place to post riddles.

Comment: I'm curious how is anyone supposed to do this without conditionals. loops and even without  numbers.

Comment: Except letters, what is left ?

Comment: In fact here you should post the code what you tried , not just tell us to write it for you.

Comment: A Fibonacci sequence without _numbers_... Who gave this _quiz_? I would like to meet the magician who can _print_ the Fibonacci sequence without numbers!

Comment: By the way, I would assume you're allowed to pass numbers into the script / function somehow, as you're saying "n is given", so the value of `n` would be in there as a number somehow?

Comment: I *did* just solve your problem, because it's fun - if you share where it can be submitted, I'd be happy to. Or share your own work and I'm happy to fix your problem, or provide my alternative.

Comment: @azro, importantly `.` is left, as well as `,` normal parentheses `(` and `)`, and finally the colon `:` - and that's all that's needed (and you're even allowed to use `_` in names, if you need to)

Comment: @Grismar, how did you calculate without numbers? Can you provide your solution?

Answer (score 2):

Because @kuro asked in the comments, here's my solution - this question will likely be closed though

```
# as n is given, assuming that is a number
n = 10


def fib(a, b, d):
    print(a)
    try:
        divmod(d, d)
        fib(b, sum((a, b)), len(range(len(((),)), d)))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass


fib(len(()), len(((),)), n)
```

Or, if you prefer a function that can just be imported and called:

```
def _fib(a, b, d):
    print(a)
    try:
        divmod(d, d)
        _fib(b, sum((a, b)), len(range(len(((),)), d)))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass


def fib(n):
    do_fib(len(()), len(((),)), n)
```

Some explanation, `divmod(d, d)` tries to divide `d` by itself, which fails with the exception given when `d` is zero. So it's the same as:

```
def _fib(a, b, d):
    print(a)
    if d:
        _fib(b, sum((a, b)), len(range(len(((),)), d)))
```

But that's not allowed, since `if` is in there.

`sum((a, b))` just sums the values of the tuple `(a, b)`, so it's the same as `a + b` and since `((),)` is a tuple that contains only 1 element, namely the empty tuple, `len(((),))` is just a complicated way to write `1`. The length of `range(1, d)` is `d` minus one, so it's all the same as:

```
def _fib(a, b, d):
    print(a)
    if d:
        _fib(b, a + b, d - 1)
```

And that's trivial.

Finally, in the initial call, `len(())` is the length of the empty tuple, so that's just `0`.

The solution hinges on realising that, to define Fibonacci's sequence, all you need are 0, 1 and the + operation, which I defined without using those symbols. And you need some way to decide when to stop without an `if`, which is the other half of the problem.

Comment: [`and`](https://tio.run/##NcrBCoQwDATQe74ixwz0oHhZFvyYSloVdmOpevDrqy2Y02TmpetYNhs@KZdiPHLfEZGGyHGdxDueHCu@xM@lvNohHu1R9qYNPWI//9Iw4PgXTLK3OUhNInC1VQBE1bf2he9sKOUG)

Comment: [`int()` and `__sub__`](https://tio.run/##Lc1BCgMhDAXQvaf4ywSktMymFHoWUXTowDQjji56eqtps0v@S5I/9XXIcs@ld8ETt6sxMa04JBE/DEaVVFsR7EmIiC3zT6xbIG8RLOIf5rJJJc/aRHiJioY425sUMw9@ce5swTnSJ/PeZHN3pDqzEO79Cw)

Comment: [non-recursive](https://tio.run/##bY0xCgMhEEV7TzHlDIgkpAkLOYvMoksEHQd3t8jpjSZVIK96xft8fR3PKre7tt4FHnC9GBPiBltakWkxMGBIAoUVM5c1MPgF2LFqlID7WUZHUNsn/YO2JAey06o4jYjsb4tsyXlfzuw9CpEx8z2n/cDvwkKOgjiEJqb3Nw) (never thought I'd do `map(lambda` again :-)

Comment: Ah, clever use of the lazy evaluation of `and`, truthiness of 0, and the fact that Python allows expressions as a statement (although your IDE will likely complain about it - it's valid Python, if not nice)

Comment: That non-recursive one is pretty gnarly, but there's something to be said for its efficiency with space and not being limited by the maximum recursion depth of course - technically it's the better one, but if someone put it in production code, I'd fire them :)

Comment: omg... now that you mention space efficiency, I realize how silly my n-tuple is. I should just [use range](https://tio.run/##bc0xCsMwDIXhXafQKEEILV1KoGcpCnZagy0Lxx16esdup0L/6Q0fPHvXZ9bL1Uprijc8nwCc33ALKwkvgD3BoJjEKEpaneB9QZnFzKuj/ZW6Y8zlQ/9kJWglmS0bjcXM068tog9PygwwbmPYK33phNErUR88gtYO).